# error C2719: '_Func': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned

Tags: c++

My goal is to apply a function that takes two arguments to a vector where I supply the second argument for each element in the vector. Specifically, I'm using the std::transform function in order to multiply a btVector3 by a transform inside my class like so:

```
btTransform COMTransform = objectToDraw->GetRigidBody()->getCenterOfMassTransform();
const btBox2dShape *plane = static_cast<const btBox2dShape*> (objectToDraw->GetShape()); 
btVector3 halfSize = plane->getHalfExtentsWithMargin();
std::vector<btVector3> vertices = {
        btVector3(-halfSize.x(), halfSize.y(), halfSize.z()),
        btVector3(halfSize.x(), halfSize.y(), halfSize.z()),
        btVector3(-halfSize.x(), -halfSize.y(), halfSize.z()),
        btVector3(halfSize.x(), -halfSize.y(), halfSize.z())
      };
std::transform(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), vertices.begin(), std::bind(TransformVertices, COMTransform, std::placeholders::_2));
```

My transform function that I am binding is:

```
static btVector3 TransformVertices( const btVector3 &vertex, const btTransform &transform) {
    return transform * vertex;
}
```

I keep getting that C2719 error even though I put const & for both my arguments.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are there apostrophes in question title - declspec(align( **'**16**'** )). [Shouldn't this argument be numeric?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx)

Comment: Probably, but that's the error that I see on my list.